Change color using an if() statement in an interaction network in R
I intended to create a function to color my network according to three conditions ( = variable abundances), but only the first one is taken into account. Do you know where is the problem ? I think there is a thing in the [1,1] because I want all my data frame to be taken into account and not just the first column.
I precise that the second condition (> 5) means the abundances between 5 and 15, but I did not how to ask properly for an interval.
Thanks a lot !
enter image description here

my_gTree <- grid.grabExpr(grid.echo(function() plotweb(sortweb(web_family, sort.order="dec"), 
                                                       method="normal",  
                                                       text.rot = 90, 
                                                       labsize = 1.5,
                                                       y.width.low = 0.08, 
                                                       y.width.high = 0.08,
                                                       col.interaction = if(web_family[1,1] > 10) { 
                                                          adjustcolor('darkturquoise', alpha.f = 0.5)})))
                                                         } else if(web_family[1,1] > 10){
                                                           adjustcolor('green', alpha.f = 0.5)
                                                           }
                                                       else if(web_family[1,1] < 10){
                                                         adjustcolor('grey', alpha.f = 0.5)})))

